# Is there any better way to refactor this code using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm calculating 3 values which are totals from the list object. so to get these i wrote 3 statements each for calculating 3 values. I would like to know is there any way i can do it better with one stream (function block ) kind of thing

Tried with 3 statments for calculating each total from the same list or streams

```
BigDecimal totalMkt = subAccounts.parallelStream()
        .flatMap(ts -> ts.getAssets().parallelStream())
        .filter(ast -> !ast.getAssetTypeCode().equals(AssetType.CURRENCY))
         .map(ast -> ast.getPostMktVal())
        .reduce(BigDecimal::add).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);

BigDecimal totalTradeVal = subAccounts.parallelStream()
        .flatMap(ts -> ts.getAssets().parallelStream())
        .filter(ast -> !ast.getAssetTypeCode().equals(AssetType.CURRENCY))
        .map(ast -> ast.getTradeVal())
        .reduce(BigDecimal::add).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);

BigDecimal totalValue = totalMkt.add(totalTradeVal).add(totalWrk);

logger.debug("totalMkt "+totalMkt+ 
            " totalTradeVal "+totalTradeVal +
            " totalWrk "+totalWrk +
            " totalValue "+totalValue);

subAccounts.stream()
        .flatMap(subAccount -> subAccount.getAssets().stream()
            .filter(asset->!asset.getAssetTypeCode().equals(AssetType.CURRENCY)))
        .forEach(asset -> {
            logger.debug("assetCode "+asset.getAssetCode());
            BigDecimal weightPct = asset.getPostMktVal()
                .multiply(new BigDecimal(100))
                .divide(totalValue, 5,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            asset.setWeightPct(weightPct);
            logger.debug(" weightPct " + weightPct);
        });
```

Newly created Pair class as suggest by  @Tarlog. Does this has any impact or issues when multiple requests came in

```
    static class Pair<L,R> {
          final L left;
          final R right;

          public L getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public R getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public Pair(L left, R right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
          }

          static <L,R> Pair<L,R> of(L left, R right){
              return new Pair<L,R>(left, right);
          }
    }
```

Comment: create a separated method and pass the necessary arguments

Comment: This probably belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.  For what it’s worth, the two things I would change:  use parameterized logging statements, so the messages don't have to be built every time;  and create a single `BigDecimal oneHundred = BigDecimal.valueOf(100);` so you aren’t creating (as many) new BigDecimal objects for every iteration.  (Or, use `movePointRight(2)` instead of multiplying.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to combine the first two statements into one:

```
Pair<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> totalMktTrade = subAccounts.parallelStream()
        .flatMap(ts -> ts.getAssets().parallelStream())
        .filter(ast -> !ast.getAssetTypeCode().equals(AssetType.CURRENCY))
         .map(ast -> Pair.of(ast.getPostMktVal(), ast.getTradeVal()))
        .reduce((a,b) -> Pair.of(a.getLeft().add(b.getLeft(), a.getRight().add(b.getRight());
BigDecimal totalMkt = totalMktTrade.getLeft();
BigDecimal totalTradeVal = totalMktTrade.getRight();
```

I cannot see how you can combine the third stream, since it uses result of previous calculation including `totalWrk` that comes from outside.

Comment: Is this Pair<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> from java 8

Comment: From apache's commons-lang

Comment: can i use map.entry instead of pair?

Comment: I assume you can. I never did it though, since Entry belongs to Map and it becomes confusing. You can also create your own class.

Comment: created my own inner class as Pair and and with static method inside. Just thinking about whether there will be any issue with multiple requests to the same method/controller

Comment: any suggestions or problems you see as Pair as an innerclass and static method "of"

Comment: Why should be there any problem? Just make sure that the class itself is static, so it's not tied to the enclosing instance.

Comment: So your update. It's perfectly fine, since of creates a new instance and the class is static.

Comment: thank for clarifying my doubts